# Removing newline after <h1> tags?

Tags: html, css, header, styles, stylesheet

I am having a problem with removing linebreaks after the `<h1>` tag, as everytime it prints, it adds a line break straight after it, so something like `<h1>Hello World!</h1> <h2>Hello Again World!</h2>` prints out like this:

```
Hello World!

Hello Again World!
```

I am unsure on what tags I need to change in CSS, but I expect it's something to do with the padding or margins

I also want to keep the vertical padding if at all possible.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Sounds like you want to format them as inline. By default, `h1` and `h2` are block-level elements which span the entire width of the line. You can change them to inline with css like this:

```
h1, h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's an article that explains the difference between `block` and `inline` in more detail: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

To maintain vertical padding, use `inline-block`, like this:

```
h1, h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If i want to add float left or right then it will not work.Then what can i do?

Answer (score 15):

`<h1>` tags have `{display: block}` set.  They are block-level elements.  To turn this off:

```
{display: inline}
```

Comment: by default h tags using margin, padding so we have to remove these

Comment: I also want to keep the vertical padding if at all possible, I have tried display: inline;, but it no longer has it's vertical padding.

Comment: removing padding and margin does not remove the new line.  the new line is caused because they are block-level elements, which mean they take up all the horizontal space where they appear (by default).  Thus unless you do floats, change display or some other properties, you will ALWAYS have a newline after an `h*` tag.

Comment: @JackWilsdon Ben Lee has already updated to show how to maintain vertical-padding easily, so I won't bother with a me too after your edit.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this problem by setting h1 margin value to minus in html style section. It works perfecly for my needs.

```
<style>
h1 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-top: -1.91em;
    margin-bottom: -1.91em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<h1 style="text-align:center"> Headline </h1>
```

Comment: This works for removing the vertical padding instead of the line break.

Comment: I googled for the wrong thing while I noticed that this answer is actually what I was looking for. Great solution, although not the answer to the question. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score -7):

```
<style>
h1 {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```