# JavaScript backspace and remove break from h1 element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to remove the break after an H1 element as well as a way to implement a backspace in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, by "remove the break," you mean not start a new line, add CSS like this:

```
h1 {display: inline;}
```

If you don't want all H1 to be that way, use a class.

As far as "implement a backspace," you will need to explain what you want to accomplish before anyone can help very much.

Comment: Ah thanks, not really good at CSS :p, as for implement a backspace, basically insert a backspace character with JavaScript to remove a character

Comment: You can just remove the character without the need of a backspace if you know where the character is, and you need to know where it is to inert the backspace.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah it would just be one space behind the caret

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932957/javascript-remove-character-from-a-string

Comment: Thank you :) sorry for the poor wording, you answered the questions perfectly though!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS style of the H1 element to come to this result. It is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361133/2433843

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

For your second part of the question, implementing a backspace, I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps you would like to strip spaces?

Comment: I'd like to remove characters :)

Answer (score 0):

This is for implementing backspace behaviour.

```
function RemoveBackspaces(str)
{
while (str.indexOf("\b") != -1)
{
    str = str.replace(/.?\x08/, ""); // 0x08 is the ASCII code for \b
}
return str;
}


   Use it like this:

   var str = RemoveBackspaces(f("\b\byz")); // returns "ayz"
```